# Hey could someone show me some code on a discord.py API? Using an api from a website

Tags: api, discord, discord.py

Im trying to create a fortnite API to give me all of the Leaked cosmetics with a discord bot and I just don't know where to get started! Could someone help! Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a simple bot that repeats what you say.

````
import discord # importing the discord.py library
from discord.ext import commands # extension of said library

# This defines the bot's command prefix and if the commands are case insensitive
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', case_insensitive='True')

@bot.event =
async def on_ready(): 
    ```
    This is an event that prints to the console that the bot is online and ready to go.
    ```
    print('Bot is ready!') # prints to console that the bot is ready.

@bot.command()
async def echo(ctx, *, msg):
    ```
    This is a command that repeats what you say. Echo is the name. *, msg means that all the words listed after the command are repeated
    ```
    await ctx.message.delete() # delete the command message the the user said
    await ctx.send(msg) # say whatever the user wanted to say.

# bot token here. found in the discord developer website
bot.run(YOUR BOT'S TOKEN GOES HERE)
````

Comment: OP wanted example of using an API, this is a generic bot example

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using a api inside a `Cog`
Necessary Imports:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Embed, Color
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from ast import literal_eval
```

A command to fetch random Chuck Norris jokes

```
    @commands.command()
    async def chuck(self, ctx):
        ad = Embed(color=Color.dark_gold())
        base = "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random"
        async with ClientSession() as session:
            data = await get(session, base)
        data = literal_eval(data)
        ad.set_author(name="Chuck Norris",
                      icon_url="https://i.ibb.co/swZqcK7/norris.gif",
                      url=data['url'])
        ad.description = data['value']
        return await ctx.send(embed=ad)
```

If you're getting information from Fortnite, chances are they already have a Python Module on PyPi, alternatively you can look for a JSON endpoint and apply what I did above to get what you need.